# Remove suggestions about legacy apps

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

If you go to your profile, Edit profile, Applications, and you have no permissions granted, or remove all and reload, you'll see some suggestions. One of them is to install the legacy SE Remote, which will take you to a dead Google's Play Store link.

[image: screenshot of relevant page within user profile, showing ad for "Stack Remote"]

Shouldn't that be removed?

Comment: Can you show a screen dump? I [don't think I see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHlh8.png)

Comment: @Scratte [sure](https://i.imgur.com/fzT41Hs.png) (It seems it doesn't always show, try reloading a few times)